# How to apply roles using HttpSecurity (Spring Security)?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3.2.3.RELEASE

And here is code of my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityContext extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(WebSecurityContext.class);

@Autowired
private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    log.info("Setting AuthenticationManagerBuilder");
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    log.info("Configuring HttpSecurity");
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

}
}
```

And result is: HTTP Status 403 - Access is denied

But if I comment this line:

```
//.antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
```

Everything works fine. Which means (I guess) something wrong with my roles or HttpSecurity.

So I started debugging. I double check that my UserDetails have two GrantedAuthorities with names: ADMIN, USER.

So any ideas what could cause the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From javadoc of the method `hasRole(String role)`:

> Shortcut for specifying URLs require a particular role. If you do not
>   want to have "**ROLE_**" automatically inserted see `hasAuthority(String)`.

So you can use `hasAuthority` or `hasAnyAuthority` instead

Comment: That's even better. Now I don't have to change my db entries. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

## Answering my own question

Apparently Spring Security automatically adds prefix ROLE_ to each role name. So adding ROLE_ prefix to each role name in my DB solved the problem.